# Can I use boto3 anonymously?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

With `boto` I could connect to public S3 buckets without credentials by passing the `anon=` keyword argument.

```
s3 = boto.connect_s3(anon=True)
```

Is this possible with `boto3`?

Answer (score 62):

Yes. Your credentials are used to sign all the requests you send out, so what you have to do is configure the client to not perform the signing step at all. You can do that as follows:

```
import boto3
from botocore import UNSIGNED
from botocore.client import Config

s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED))
# Use the client
```

Comment: it would be nice to update this answer with an up to date solution.

Comment: I tested and it works on 2022. You just need to add the region_name to the client parameters, something like this: s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED),region_name='us-east-1')

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore in 2023, even with region_name set.

Comment: this worked for me on a known public bucket, with `region_name` set to `us-east-1`, albeit I was creating a boto s3 resource, not a boto s3 client. see https://www.learnaws.org/2021/02/24/boto3-resource-client/

Comment: Tried this recently on a known public bucket and it works even without the `region_name`.

Comment: This worked for me without specifying region_name. Thanks @Jordon Phillips

Answer (score 26):

Disable signing

```
import boto3

from botocore.handlers import disable_signing
resource = boto3.resource('s3')
resource.meta.client.meta.events.register('choose-signer.s3.*', disable_signing)
```

Comment: Will this stop credentials from being used if they are present?  Is it suitable to set as a default?

Comment: It will stop credentials from being used on that client. You will need another client to connect to restricted s3 buckets. The same is true of my solution. Note: both solutions do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

None of these seem to work as of the current boto3 version (1.9.168). This hack (courtesy of an unfixed github issue on botocore) does seem to do the trick:

```
client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='', aws_secret_access_key='')
client._request_signer.sign = (lambda *args, **kwargs: None)
```

Comment: [Jordon Phillips` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34866092/974555) appears to work for me on boto3 1.9.251.