# AWS Boto3 get file list without authentication

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I was wondering if someone can help me with this. I am trying to get a list of files in an s3 bucket by using boto3 without authenticating. I can accomplish this using `aws s3 ls  s3://mysite.com/ --no-sign-request --region us-east-2`, but I am trying to do this in a pythonic manner using boto3.

Currently, when I try using boto.session.Session(), it is asking for credentials.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think a `Session` always requires credentials. You should be able to disable signing and use `boto3.resource('s3')` to access the bucket instead.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865927/can-i-use-boto3-anonymously):

```
from botocore.handlers import disable_signing
resource = boto3.resource('s3')
resource.meta.client.meta.events.register('choose-signer.s3.*', disable_signing)
```

And then it should be a case of:

```
bucket = resource.Bucket('mysite.com')

for item in bucket.objects.all():
    print(item.key)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!