# Unable to download a file from Amazon s3 with Python (no credentials)

Tags: python, file, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download

How do I download from a public repository with Python?

https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/WQ3/?region=us-West-2&tab=overview

My code:

```
import boto3

s3client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-West-2')
objects = s3client.list_objects(Bucket='WQ3')

    raise NoCredentialsError
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use boto3 anonymously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865927/can-i-use-boto3-anonymously)

Comment: @jarmod No accepted answer, so I'm questioning if any of those solutions were helpful.

Comment: Did you try them? Both worked for me.

Comment: Solution that does not require credentials (no boto3) [Download file/folder from Public AWS S3 with Python, no credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62086013/download-file-folder-from-public-aws-s3-with-python-no-credentials)